# Processing a large XLSX file: Maximum call stack exceeded in Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, promise, rabbitmq, event-loop

I have been trying to fix a bug while processing a large xlsx file with 30,000 rows. Below is the code I am having issues in.

```
const readXlsxFile = require('read-excel-file/node');

    readXlsxFile(filename, {schema}).then((rows) => {
        rows = rows.rows
        let productsDetails = []
        rows.forEach((row, index) => {
            Object.keys(db.productInventory.rawAttributes).forEach((column) => {
                let data;
                try {
                     <if else conditions for edge cases>
                     }
                  })
                 }
               })
```

`schema` object has around 30 attributes, please ignore the brackets if missing.

The above code works with 1000 rows xlsx file.

I tried to debug and put breakpoints inside the .then() function, but debugger doesn't reach there.

I am getting following errors when I hit run the code.

> Disconnected. Error: write EPIPE
>       at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:789:14)
>
> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I am not able to figure out how to solve this issue. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

It has worked for me when I used this flag

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 index.js
```

There is a strict standard limit for the memory usage in V8 of around 1.7 GB if you do not increase it manually. But if you still have a problem and it's not working, try this library, it's useful.
https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

```
const fs = require('fs');
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

const xlsxFile = 'all_records.xlsx';
const outputFileName = "output.json";

const workbook = XLSX.read(xlsxFile, { type: 'file' });
const [firstSheetName] = workbook.SheetNames;
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName];
const rows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
      header: 'A',
      range: 0,
      blankrows: false,
      defval: null,
      raw: true,
});

const stream = fs.createWriteStream(outputFileName, {flags: 'w'});
stream.write(JSON.stringify(rows));
```